# Doctrine one-to-many relationship AND many-to-one

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, cascade, relationships

I have two tables. I want to set up a one-to-many relationship, but also a many-to-one relationship.

A Page can have one Background - this is the background of the page.

A Page can also have many Backgrounds - this is a collection of user-uploaded backgrounds from which one will be chosen for the first relationship.

In other words, a user selects a background from a bunch of predefined backgrounds, or one of many backgrounds he has uploaded to try out.

edit: When deleting a background, I want all pages with that background_id to have background_id set to null. When deleting a page, I want all the custom backgrounds belonging to that page to be deleted.

Whilst doctrine and symfony allow the above configuration, when deleting the page Doctrine ignores cascade="{remove}" on the Backgrounds property entirely, and of course an exception is raised when trying to delete the Page before deleting it's custom Backgrounds.

What am I doing wrong?

```
class Background
{
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * This attribute is for user uploaded backgrounds.
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Page",inversedBy="customBackgrounds")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="page_id",referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $page;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * This field helps admins to gauge popularity
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Page",mappedBy="background")
 */
protected $pages;
}


class Page
{
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Background",inversedBy="pages")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="background_id",referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
 */
protected $background;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Background", mappedBy="page", cascade={"remove"})
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"id" = "ASC"})
 */
protected $customBackgrounds;
}
```

Comment: I should mention that removing the $background property and ManyToOne relationship annotation perfectly restores the cascade remove functionality when deleting a page (deleting it's custom backgrounds) - but this is of course not what I want to do.

Comment: dariusphp has successfully solved my problem but it makes no sense to me. I'm using cascade={"remove"} to remove other related objects when I delete and I don't use `onDelete="SET NULL"` for those. I undestand that `onDelete="SET NULL"` works at the dbms level to orphan related objects when their parent is deleted. How does this help doctrine to delete the related objects when their parent is deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try
`@ORM\JoinColumn(name="page_id",referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")` and do a schema update.

**EDIT**: The problem is at the database level not at doctrine's, the cascade="remove" takes care of that, the foreign key for page_id however, stays, the onDelete indicates that if a column with that foreign relationship is deleted, set the field to "value" this case its null. if you --dump-sql before schema update'ing you would see the query addition, something along the lines of " ON DELETE SET * "

More Info can be found Here:
http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_null.php

Comment: But won't that just orphan the custom backgrounds when I delete a page?

Comment: I've tried it out and I just get the same error:

    "An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM Page WHERE id = ?' with params [16]:  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`project`.`Background`, CONSTRAINT `FK_F335B7807B40E4F7` FOREIGN KEY (`page_id`) REFERENCES `Page` (`id`))"

Comment: Apologies, I've tried your answer again and it does work - and the backgrounds are actually deleted - which isn't what I would expect this to do. Thanks @dariusphp!

Comment: If you can edit your answer to provide a reasonable explanation of why this works I'll award you the bounty.

Comment: OK, that page explains to me what I already knew - that `onDelete SET NULL` nulls the foreign keys on the child table but " The records in the child table will *not* be deleted". Doctrine's documentation never suggests you add this condition to child tables you want to cascade remove, and I've not used it in the past in any other circumstance. In fact I have other child entities relating to the `page` entity that are cascade deleted without adding this condition. It only seems necessary when I have the second relationship back the other way. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that maybe you can do, is use an event listener in your entity and when a page is deleted, set its background to null or another id

Comment: But I want the custom backgrounds to be deleted when the page is deleted, and the page's background_id to be set to null when the Background is deleted...

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Background", mappedBy="page", orphanRemoval=true)
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"id" = "ASC"})
 */
protected $customBackgrounds;
```

Should do the trick ([Doctrine - Orphan Removal](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal))